# Is there "pass by reference"(C++) in go?

Tags: go

I am defined a function using pointer, like the following

```
func concat(head1, head2 *Node) Node {
}
```

and pass in pointer. but I am wondering if Go supports pass by reference like C++ which I could use like the following

```
func concat(head1, head2 &Node) Node
```

Comment: No. Everything in go is by value.

Comment: C++ pass-by-reference is arguably just a fancy way of doing a const pointer.

Comment: Go implements a different helper: it allows you most of the time to directly use the dot-name notation to call methods on pointer value w/o dereferencing them explicitly.

Comment: And IMO references in C++ are ill-concieved as they hide the fact pointers are taken at the call site. As a demonstration, C#, which came much later, requires using of explicit keywords `ref` or `out` at the call site exactly for the programmer to understand what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)
>
> In a function call, the function value and arguments are evaluated in
>   the usual order. After they are evaluated, the parameters of the call
>   are passed by value to the function and the called function begins
>   execution. The return parameters of the function are passed by value
>   back to the calling function when the function returns.

---

No. Parameters are passed by value.